# Querying for all rows matching multiple tags

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a object called photo with an attribute called multitag of type array. For ex photo A has tag desk, photo B has tag chair and photo C has tags desk,chair. If user searches for desk, A is returned. If user searches for chair B is returned. If user searches for desk chair C is returned first folllowed by A and B. How do you do that using PFQuery?

Comment: Read the documentation https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-arrays/iOS

Comment: Hi  Björn, I edited the question. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would do this particular type of data relationships using tags in arrays.  You are better off using pointers or relations for this task.

For example:

the `Photo` class has a column `tag` which is a `ParseRelation` column type that points to the `Tag` class.  For each photo in the `Photo` class you will add as many `Tag` objects to the `Photo.tag` column as you wish.  This makes it very easy to query for and it is scales better than using arrays.

[Here is the Parse guide on using Relations](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide)